# ZF2: Trying to understand Zend\Form

Tags: forms, zend-framework2

I'm new to Zend and honestly frameworks\larger scale OOP projects in general. I think figuring out how this little piece works would go a long why to improving my understanding. When using setAttribute to register the form with a controller, what is actually reading the `ur()` property I set?

Here is a  snippet:

```
$form = $this->form;
$form->prepare();
$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url(NULL,
    array('controller'=>'Register','action'=> 'process')));
$form->setAttribute('method','post');
echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
```

What is actually reading `'controller'=>'Register'` and associating it with my `Register` controller?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This part of your code:

```
$this->url(NULL, array('controller'=>'Register','action'=> 'process'))
```

is calling the [URL helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.url.html). This call will output a path, based on your routing configuration, along the lines of `/register/process`. You are setting the 'action' attribute of the form to this value, giving you HTML something along the lines of:

```
<form method="post" action="/register/process">
```

so that's what makes the form submit to your register controller.